# Расположить централизованно рядом друг с другом две кнопки

Tags: css, css3

Есть две nav `buttons`, как их расположить централизованно рядом друг c другом.

Больше интересует как их параметры совместить в один класс, чтобы не писать 2 одинаковых класса, с отличием только в цвете.

ПО возможности хотел бы получить ответ на два этих простых вопроса.

```css
.button {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);;
 color:#fff;
 display: block;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 22px;
 margin-top: 275px;   
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
```

```html
  <a class= "button1" href="#">BOOK A TABLE</a>
           <a class= "button2" href="#">SEE THE MENU</a>
```

[image: как нужно]

[image: Как сейчас]

Comment: Нужно как на pic1

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center; /* центрируем элементы с display:inline-block; */
}

.button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 22px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-light {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  border-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <a class="button" href="#">BOOK A TABLE</a>
  <a class="button button-light" href="#">SEE THE MENU</a>
</div>
```

Comment: по первому ответу ответ есть.  
спасибо. Можно-ли все в один класс объединить? что бы не было:
.button-light 
.button
а был один класс .button ?

Comment: @Vladyslav Volshev - нет нельзя